# Omnipay PHPUnit Guzzle httpClient 404 Error - mock json

Tags: php, unit-testing, phpunit, guzzle, omnipay

I'm new to [OmniPay](https://github.com/thephpleague/omnipay), playing around with it and trying to make a simple custom gateway, and create a unit test with a mock json http response.

In the GatewayTest.php I set a mock http response:

```
public function testPurchaseSuccess()
{
    $this->setMockHttpResponse('TransactionSuccess.txt');

    $response = $this->gateway->purchase($this->options)->send();

    echo $response->isSuccessful();

    $this->assertEquals(true, $response->isSuccessful());
}
```

In the PurchaseRequest.php I'm trying to get it somehow:

```
public function sendData($data)
{
    $httpResponse = //how do I get the mock http response set before?

    return $this->response = new PurchaseResponse($this, $httpResponse->json());
}
```

So how do I get the mock http response in PurchaseRequest.php?

**--- UPDATE ---**

It turned out that in my PurchaseResponse.php

```
use Omnipay\Common\Message\RequestInterface;

//and...

public function __construct(RequestInterface $request, $data)
{
    parent::__construct($request, $data);
}
```

was missing.

Now with `$httpResponse = $this->httpClient->post(null)->send();` in PurchaseRequest.php the assertions are OK, but when I use httpClient, Guzzle throws a 404 error. I checked [Guzzle's docs](http://guzzle3.readthedocs.org/testing/unit-testing.html#queueing-mock-responses) and tried to create a mock response, but then again my assertions fail and 404 remains:

PurchaseRequest.php

```
public function sendData($data)
{
    $plugin = new Guzzle\Plugin\Mock\MockPlugin();
    $plugin->addResponse(new Guzzle\Http\Message\Response(200));

    $this->httpClient->addSubscriber($plugin);

    $httpResponse = $this->httpClient->post(null)->send(); 

    return $this->response = new PurchaseResponse($this, $httpResponse->json());

}
```

Any suggestions, how to get rid of the 404?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so here is what turned out to be the solution:

**Original Problem**

This was missing from my PucrhaseResponse.php:

```
use Omnipay\Common\Message\RequestInterface;

//and...

public function __construct(RequestInterface $request, $data)
{
    parent::__construct($request, $data);
}
```

PurchaseRequest.php:

```
public function sendData($data)
{
    $httpResponse = $this->httpClient->post(null)->send();

    return $this->response = new PurchaseResponse($this, $httpResponse->json());
}
```

**Solving the 404 problem in the update**

In order to prevent Guzzle from throwing exceptions I had to add a listener for request.error.

PurchaseRequest.php:

```
public function sendData($data)
{
    $this->httpClient->getEventDispatcher()->addListener(
        'request.error',
        function (\Guzzle\Common\Event $event) {
            $event->stopPropagation();
        }
    );

    $httpResponse = $this->httpClient->post(null)->send(); 

    return $this->response = new PurchaseResponse($this, $httpResponse->json());
}
```